# Need two table column data in same time with no duplicate entry

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Need two table column data in same time with no duplicate entry
how to get two table same data with diffrent column name -> no duolicate entry

[image: project_cashflow_attrs Table]
[image: retainer_cashflow_attrs Table]

My Laravel Query

```
$overallmonth = DB::table('project_cashflow_attrs')
                    ->select('month','rca.retainer_month')
                    ->crossjoin('retainer_cashflow_attrs as rca')
                    ->groupby('month','rca.retainer_month')
                    ->get();
```

I need data like this from tables

> May-2023 June-2023 July-2023

Comment: Mysql is not SQL server - please correct your tags

Comment: Please do not use this images for data, use formatted tabular text

Comment: It seems that you need not in JOIN but in UNION.

Comment: can you add an example of your output just raw texts? and yes as @Akina said you'll need union.

Comment: I do not use Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the unique months from the `month` column in `project_cashflow_attrs` and the `retainer_month` column in `retainer_cashflow_attrs` you can use the union and pluck methods in Laravel.
Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
$months = DB::table('project_cashflow_attrs')
    ->select('month')
    ->distinct()
    ->union(DB::table('retainer_cashflow_attrs')->select('retainer_month'))
    ->pluck('month');
```